# Hide count in the “All Groups” tab in Buddypress groups page

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I use BuddyPress on my site. In the groups page I'd like to hide the count in the "All Groups" tab and also the line "Viewing 1 - X of XX groups", as I don't want users to know the total number of groups.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible options. It looks like this is controlled by this file:

```
/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-groups/bp-groups-template.php
```

1) A hacky approach would be to just edit that file, looking for the bp_groups_pagination_count() function and manually editing it. However, that may get overwritten on the next BP update.

2) A better approach would be to [create a BP Child Theme](https://codex.buddypress.org/legacy/theme-development/the-bp-default-theme/building-a-buddypress-child-theme/) and override that file/function

3) You may also be able to [apply a filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) to the bp_groups_pagination_count() function, by adding something like this to your theme's functions.php file:

```
apply_filters('bp_groups_pagination_count','__return_empty_string');
```